# How to do code-review and submit with git command like 'git commit'?

Tags: git, command-line, submit

I would like to do code-review and submit with git command line, since git support commit by cmmand line, so which command of git can do the the code-review and submit?

Comment: Code-reviews are not a git feature. All you can do is commit to a certain remote branch and let a git repository management framework, like GitHub or GitLab, handle your code reviews via mechanisms like pull or merge requests.

Comment: @kowsky Could you explain regarding 'handle your code reviews via mechanisms like pull or merge requests' ?

Comment: If you use GitLab as repository management framework, you can issue merge requests to merge one branch into another *in GitLab*. If you use GitHub as repository management framework, you can issue pull requests to merge one branch into another *in GitHub*. Both are framework specific ways to perform code reviews. Git itself does not offer such mechanisms. If you want a convenient way to review code, you will need to use a platform. There are plenty: GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket...

Comment: @kowsky get it, thanks for your detail explain.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in comments above, *code reviews* are not built-in to git. But git allows you to be very creative when it comes to your workflow.

Here you find two very popular workflows (*Git Flow* and *GitHub Flow*) discussed in detail: https://youtu.be/ww4xpcvzLHc. Both of which make use of *code reviews* before code changes are *merged* or *pulled* into the "productive" envoronment (i.e. the *master branch* or *origin repo*).